# How can I copy the same to code to a different sheet without changing the sheet name?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do you write the code to auto detect the sheet name when copy to a different sheet

```
Sub SendEmail(address As String, subject As String, mail_body As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailStream
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        olMail.To = address
        olMail.Subject = subject
        olMail.Body = mail_body
        olMail.Send


    Sub SendAllEmail()

    row_number = 2

    Do
    DoEvents

    row_number = row_number + 1
    //the sheet1 is hardcoded for the particular sheet which want to convert i to a variable
    Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)Sheet2.Range("B3"),Sheet2.Range("B4"))

    Loop Until row_number = 6

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. You want to autodetect the sheet you're copying from?

Comment: Place your code in ThisWorkbook module (do not copy to individual worksheets) and make the code execution logic conditional (or non-conditional) on sheet name. Rgds,

Comment: Yes so instead of hard coding the sheet name i have to declare a variable which should automatically detect the sheet name where i copy the code to and execute the same function. So this code is basically to send mass email to people in a column by clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to the sheet the code is in (without knowing which it is), just use `Me` - e.g.

```
Me.Range("A" & row_number)
```

But as Alex Bell suggests, a more efficient approach is likely to be to change the code to handle any sheet, and write it once in ThisWorkbook (or in its own module).  For example:

In ThisWorkbook:

```
Sub example(objSheet as Worksheet)
  'I can refer to a cell on objSheet like so:
  SendEmail objSheet.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Which can be called from code on a specific worksheet like so:

```
example(Me)
```

Do note that if you have a worksheet with a button that runs code within that worksheet, and you just copy the sheet, the new button still calls the code on the old sheet (even though the new sheet has a copy of the code as well!)

Comment: So When I copy the code to another sheet will I need to add this function every time "example(Me)"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [Application.ActiveSheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb212495%28v=office.12%29.aspx), which is the currently active worksheet.

Comment: Would I need to replace the actual sheet name which is "sheet1.range" with "Application.ActiveSheet"???

Comment: @user2971393 Replace "sheet1.range" with "Application.ActiveSheet.range".

Answer (score 0):

//When I run this code on a different sheet it says member or data method not found

```
Sub SendEmail(address_mail As String, subject_mail As String, mail_body As String)


Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = address_mail
    olMail.Subject = subject_mail
    olMail.Body = mail_body

   On Error GoTo Cancel

    olMail.Send

Cancel:

End Sub
Sub SendMassEmail()

Dim addressString As String
addressString = ""
row_number = 2



Do
DoEvents

    row_number = row_number + 1
    addressString = addressString & Me.Range("C" & row_number) & ";"


    Loop Until row_number = 999
Call SendEmail(addressString, Me.Range("F9"), Me.Range("F10"))

End Sub

Sub repeatFunction(objSheet As Worksheet)
SendMassEmail objSheet.Range("C" & row_number)
End Sub
```